# Getting an error: Type 'String' has no member 'foregroundColor' in Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift

I am new to Swift. I created an app in Swift 4, but when I change the SWIFT_VERSION to Swift 3.0, I get an error in my code.

> Type 'String' has no member 'foregroundColor'.

How can I convert this to current Swift syntax?

Code:

```
    if let p = placeholder {

      let place = NSAttributedString(string: p, attributes: //error -->[.foregroundColor: #colorLiteral(red: 1.0, green: 1.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)])


        attributedPlaceholder = place

        textColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1.0, green: 1.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)
```

Answer (score 8):

Attributed string attributes are not enums before Swift 4. You should use `NSForegroundColorAttributeName` in this case.

```
NSAttributedString(string: p, attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: #colorLiteral(red: 1.0, green: 1.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)])
```

Comment: Thank you... Also, out of this question: Can you upload Swift 4 app to itunes connect now? or its early?

Comment: You can't upload to the App Store with a beta version of Xcode