# Swift 4.1: Type 'String' has no member 'foregroundColor'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods

I have the below line of code in a cocoa pod which I am compiling in Swift 4.1 on Xcode.

```
let foregroundColor = attributedTitle(for: .normal)?.attribute(.foregroundColor, at: 0, effectiveRange: nil) as? UIColor
```

The error I am getting for the line is:

```
Type 'String' has no member 'foregroundColor'
```

There is a similar discussion here [Getting an error: Type 'String' has no member 'foregroundColor' in Swift 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45422048/getting-an-error-type-string-has-no-member-foregroundcolor-in-swift-4) but what confuses me is that this answer suggests the error I am seeing is in fact one to do with Swift 3.X whereas I am compiling in Swift 4.1.

Also, when I try to edit the line it is blocked (as it is from a cocoa pod) which makes me wonder if there isn't another way of soling it (as messing with the pods will cause a problem every time I update in the future)?

Comment: What that part **attributedTitle(for: .normal)**  ??

Comment: which Cocoapod is this and what is `attributedTitle` declared as?

Comment: Maybe its sth about compatibility mode?

Comment: It is part of the https://cocoapods.org/pods/Adyen cocoa pod. I don't really know what that line does as it's deep into the cocoa pod.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i hope `attributedTitle(for: .normal)` is a fuction who return a String value, but your code is prepared to recive an attributedString like this:

```
let attributeTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "StringExample")
let color = attributeTitle.attribute(.foregroundColor, at: 0, effectiveRange: nil) as? UIColor
```

the problem i hope is the function attributedTitle, search him in the pod and try tu change the return value or check if an update in the library is uploaded.

Comment: Thank you Alejandro. I have now reverted to the previous version of the Adyen cocoa pod which does not have the problem. I will wait for another update in the cocoa pod to see if the problem has been rectified there.